# רָעָ֔ה in Jeremiah 29:11 - what part of speech?

Tags: hebrew, grammar

In this fragment of Jeremiah 29:11 (plans of shalom and not evil):

```
מַחְשְׁבֹ֤ות שָׁלֹום֙ וְלֹ֣א לְרָעָ֔ה
```

I've got Bible Works (v6) parsing לְרָעָ֔ה as an adjective (with leading particle preposition).

On the other hand, it seems to align with TWOT 2191c (listed as parent noun of verb).

What is the part of speech for רָעָ֔ה in Jeremiah 29:11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noun, feminine, secondary form of רעע, meaning a disaster, defeat, social disorder. See also II Kings 21:12 Jeremiah 17:17, Psalms 91:10.

I would translate here (Jeremiah 29:11) as "Intents of peace and not for evil", adding an explicit translation of the ל in לרעה.

Can also mean evil or an evil deed. Compare Genesis 39:9, I Samuel 25:21, II Samuel 3:39.

Might be better if you used a standard Hebrew dictionary like the Even Shoshan.

Comment: Appreciate the thoughtfulness and pointer to improved reference material.